# Angular Ionic HTTP promise not working how it should

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-http

I have a service which gets endpoint data :

**Service.ts**

```
  getAllProducts(){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      this.apiService.get( this.allProducts, `/products`, {} )
        .then( data => resolve( data.map( item => this.parseProductDetails( item ) ) ) )
        .catch( err => reject( err ) );
    } );
  }
```

`console.log(data)` - gives all products. Everything okey in service.And the  function this.parseProductDetails also returns all products normally.

But when I call from component :

```
ionViwDidLoad(){
  this.productProvider.getAllProducts()
          .then( () => {
            items => this.items = items; 
            console.log('All products', this.items)
          }  )
          .catch( err => console.debug( 'products not found', err ) )
}
```

`console.log('All products', this.items)` - nothing in console log returned, not even undefined or All products text.

What is wrong with this code and what I have to change that I could retrieve information in component ?

parseProductDetails(item) :

```
protected parseProductDetails( data: any ): Object {
    let parsed: any = data;

    try {
      parsed.dimensions = JSON.parse( data.dimensions );
    } catch( e ) { parsed.dimensions = []; }

    if( data.price )
      parsed.priceFormatted = this.formatPrice( data.price, data.currency );
    else
      parsed.priceFormatted = false;

    if( data.delivery )
      parsed.deliveryFormatted = this.formatPrice( data.delivery, data.currency );
    else
      parsed.deliveryFormatted = false;

    if( data.stock )
      parsed.stockFormatted = this.formatStock( data.stock, data.stockUnit );
    else
      parsed.stockFormatted = false;

    return parsed;
  }
```

return parsed gives array.

Comment: Try to move `loading.dismiss()` function into your first `then` and remove the second one `.then( () => loading.dismiss() )`.

Comment: Do you have any reason for using Promise over Observable? You can use Observables as response from services, and then use toPromise() and use it as Promise. So you have something like this.productProvider.getAllProducts().toPromise().then(...).

Comment: Then dismiss never happens.

Comment: And Promise vs Observable - there is nothing bad to use Promise specially if I need only to retrieve information.

Answer (score 0):

the issues on promise then callback :

```
this.productProvider.getAllProducts()
      .then((items) => {
        console.log('All products', items)
      }  )
      .catch( err => console.debug( 'products not found', err ) )
      .then( () => loading.dismiss() );
```

Comment: Still nothing in console.log

Comment: try  console.log( data.map( item => this.parseProductDetails( item ))

Comment: i think map data return empty value  @AndrėjusLazauskas

Answer (score 0):

You are using two arrow functions inside `then()`. you should remove one.

```
ionViwDidLoad(){
  this.productProvider.getAllProducts()
          .then( (items) => {
            this.items = items; 
            console.log('All products', this.items)
          })
          .catch( err => console.debug( 'products not found', err ) )
          .then( () => loading.dismiss() );
}
```

Comment: Removed, didn't help. I copied it to my first then() , and loading never dissmisses.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot going wrong here. I don't know what is the exact cause, but I guess the `items` parameter not being placed correctly. Try this:

```
getAllProducts() {
  return this.apiService.get(this.allProducts, `/products`, {}).then((data) => { 
    console.log('items', data);
    return data.map((item) => this.parseProductDetails(item))
  });
}
```

Which you call like:

```
ionViwDidLoad(){
  this.productProvider.getAllProducts()
    .then((items) => {
      this.items = items;
      console.log('All products', this.items)
    })
    .catch((err) => console.debug( 'products not found', err ))
    .then(() => loading.dismiss());
}
```

Comment: Tryed your variaton, still nothing in console.log - if it wrong in a lot of ways, what would be good way of calling http promise and retrieving it ?

Comment: @AndrėjusLazauskas the way I wrote it down works. Although you could look into observable streams in combination with the `async` pipe. Just don't use nested Promises :)

Comment: @AndrėjusLazauskas what is exactly in the `console.log`? Null, undefined, or an empty array?

Comment: It is nothing - nothing in console. Seems like that function just didnt start after then.

Comment: so the `this.apiService.get`doesn't seem to be correct. Can you add that implementation to your question?

Comment: It is working correctly, I have my Array in Network response.

Comment: @AndrėjusLazauskas still, for completeness, can you add it? But the `loading.dismiss()` does get called? Then it feels like it gets into the `catch` statement. But the `products not found` is not logged?

Comment: What exactly I should add to my question - because I don't really know what is wrong in my api call ?

Comment: The other thing is , when I swap catch with then  - i get "All products" undefined.

Comment: maybe `console.debug` doesn't work for you somehow, can you change that to `console.error`, perhaps a more clear error will show up. If that doesn't work, can you show the implementation of `this.parseProductDetails`

Comment: added function to my question .

Comment: @AndrėjusLazauskas very difficult to tell what's wrong, it seems like some error is swallowed somewhere. Can you nevertheless post the `this.apiService.get` implementation?

Comment: I do not have that function its from aws amplify. Other endpoints working normally, just this one works weirdly.

Comment: I've added a `console.log` in the getAllProducts. Can you check if it reaches there? and if it has data\

Comment: and It returns array of items as I have told before.

Answer (score 0):

use async && await

```
async getAllProducts()
await this.productProvider.getAllProducts()
```